# Ошибка в php коде, можете помочь

Tags: php, sql

```
>**Fatal error**: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function `select()` on 
`string` in C:\OSPanel\domains\phplog\index.php:12   
*Stack trace:*   
 #0 {main} thrown in C:\OSPanel\domains\phplog\index.php on line 12
```

Вот код index.php

```
<?php include 'config/config.php'; ?>
<?php include 'libraries/database.php'; ?>
<?php include 'includes/header.php'; ?>
<?php
//Create DB Object
$db = 'database';

//Create Query
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts";

//Run Query
$posts = $db->select($query);

?>
<?php if($posts) : ?>
<div class="blog-post">
<h2 class="blog-post-title">Another blog post</h2>
<p class="blog-post-meta">December 23, 2013 by <a href="#">Jacob</a></p>
<p>text.</p>
<a class="readmore" href="post.php?id=1">read more</a>
</div><!-- /.blog-post -->

<div class="blog-post">
<h2 class="blog-post-title">Another blog post</h2>
<p class="blog-post-meta">December 23, 2013 by <a href="#">Jacob</a></p>
<p>text.</p>
<a class="readmore" href="post.php?id=1">read more</a>
</div><!-- /.blog-post -->
<?php else : ?>
<p>Thete are no posts yet</p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php include 'includes/footer.php'; ?>
```

Вот код database.php

```
<?php 
class database{
public $host = db_host;
public $username = db_username;
public $password = db_pass;
public $db_name = db_name;

public $link;
public $error;

/*
 * Class Constructor
 */
public function __construct(){
    //Call Connect Function
    $this->connect();
}

/*
 * Connector
 */
private function connect() {
    $this->link = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, 
$this->db_name);

    if(!$this->link) {
        $this->error = "Connection Failed: ".$this->link->connect_error;
        return false;
    }
}

/*
 * Select
 */
public function select($query) {
    $result = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link-
>error.__LINE__);
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        return $result;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

/*
 * Insert
 */
public function insert($query) {
    $insert_row = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link-
>error.__LINE__);

    //Validate Insert
    if($insert_row) {
        header("Location: index.php?msq=".urlencode('Record insert'));
        exit();
    }
}

/*
 * Update
 */
public function update($query) {
    $update_row = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link-
>error.__LINE__);

    //Validate update
    if($update_row) {
        header("Location: index.php?msq=".urlencode('Record update'));
    }
}
}
?>
```

И вот код подключения самой бд config.php

```
<?php
define('db_host', 'localhost');
define('db_user', 'root');
define('db_pass', '');
define('db_name', 'blog');
?>
```

Comment: $db у вас строка (текст), а не объект для работы с БД

Comment: <?php
 //Create DB Object
 $db = 'database';
 
 //Create Query
 $query = 'SELECT * FROM posts';
 
 //Run Query
 $posts = $db->select($query);
 
?>

Comment: что еще раз подтверждает первый комментарий

Comment: ага, у вас в качестве соединения с БД почему то выступает простая надпись 'database'. С таким же успехом можно написать на асфальте "самолёт" и ожидать когда он полетит

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.connections.php

Comment: а в pdo вообще существует ли метод `select`? насколько мне известно в pdo выборка производится так `$posts = $db->query('SELECT * FROM posts');`

Comment: @ИгорьСаламов а как будет выглядеть эта строчка в php 7  $db = new database();

Comment: @Mike посмотрите, вот я скинул 3 файла. может просто ошибка не только в d index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка связана с тем, что вы вместо создания объекта присваиваете строку.
Необходимо исправить index.php следующим образом:

```
<?php 
//убрал лишние php-теги
include 'config/config.php';
include 'libraries/database.php';
include 'includes/header.php';

//Create DB Object
$db = new database(); //здесь создаем объект класса database, как и сказано комментарием выше

//Create Query
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts";

//Run Query
$posts = $db->select($query);

?>
<?php if($posts) : ?>
<div class="blog-post">
<h2 class="blog-post-title">Another blog post</h2>
<p class="blog-post-meta">December 23, 2013 by <a href="#">Jacob</a></p>
<p>text.</p>
<a class="readmore" href="post.php?id=1">read more</a>
</div><!-- /.blog-post -->

<div class="blog-post">
<h2 class="blog-post-title">Another blog post</h2>
<p class="blog-post-meta">December 23, 2013 by <a href="#">Jacob</a></p>
<p>text.</p>
<a class="readmore" href="post.php?id=1">read more</a>
</div><!-- /.blog-post -->
<?php else : ?>
<p>Thete are no posts yet</p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php include 'includes/footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Тогда выдает 4 ошибки  Warning: Use of undefined constant 
    db_username - assumed 'db_username' (this will throw an Error in 
    a future version of PHP) in C:\OSPanel\domains\phplog\index.php 
    on line 6

Comment: Как я понял проблемы с версией php, так как у меня версия 7.2

Comment: В файле database.php заменить строчку public $username = db_username; на public $username = db_user; либо в конфиге константу подправьте

Comment: Воо, спасибо огромное, а то голову ломал)

Comment: Очень помогли!!!